# Differential and log backup on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-3.4

Is it possible to take differential and log backup on mongodb like on microsoft SQL server?

Comment: ,Welcome to the site . I am sure it is duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974071/want-to-do-an-incremental-backup-for-mongodb-journaling-oplog and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194280/is-it-possible-to-take-incremental-backup-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is completely different from MSSQL server. And you can't take Differential and Log backup directly from MongoDB. But you can try OpLog backup method, but I never encourage to use this in production.

## My Suggestions:

- Use replica set with delayed commit node.
- Use LVM snapshots.
- If you are using AWS, take EBS volume level backups.

## For your question:

- [Here is answer for your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25237379/6885516)
- [An OpenSource project](https://github.com/journeyapps/mongo-oplog-backup)